# Using SaxonEE 9.9.1 with XSLT2.0 getting error Reflexive calls to Java methods require a Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE license, and none was found

Tags: java, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using SAXONEE with XSLT 2.0. In order fix this issue is ExtensionFunction is the way?
To import my JAVA class below is code I am using:

```
xmlns:myclass="java:com.output.extensionFile"
```

And line that I am getting error is:

```
<xsl:param name="output" select="myclass:getFilePath(myclass:new())"/>
```

Error I get:

Static error near {...s:getFilePath(myclass:new...} at char 22 in expression in xsl:param/@select on line 78 column 73 :
XPST0017: Cannot find a 0-argument function named
Q{java:com.output.extensionFile}new(). Cannot load Java
class java:com.output.extensionFile. Reflexive calls to
Java methods require a Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE license, and none was found

tried defining this way too:

```
<xsl:param name="output" select="nd:getFilePath()" xmlns:nd="java:com.output.extensionFile"/>
```

Comment: And you have the licence file at the correct location?

Comment: what is the expected location for license file? actually I myself never handled such file, mean what should be its location

Comment: See https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/about/license/licensekey.html

Comment: suppose I use HE as it won't need license key, will the import of JAVA class syntax differs?

Comment: The subject says you use EE, for EE you need a license and to use reflexive extension functions like you seem to try you indeed need at least PE or EE as HE doesn't support that. Extension functions (integrated they are called) for HE are documented in https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-J/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Saxon version 9.1.0.8 which is, I believe, the last version of Saxon which implemented java extension functions in the *"Basic"* or non-licensed version.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a feature in Saxon which will only work if three conditions are satisfied:

(a) the software you use is the PE or EE version

(b) the APIs you use enable the PE/EE functionality (for example, you start loading Saxon with a call to `new Processor(true)` rather than `new Processor(false)`

(c) you have a valid license file and install this in the right place.

The error message strongly suggests that it's (c) that's the problem. There is documentation on setting up license files at

https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!about/license

Comment: as you have mentioned new Processor, does this mean with SaxonEE I would need extension function, beside that I cannot directly call my JAVA class function inside XSL?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. You are trying to call a Java method in an extension function call, and you can do that with Saxon-EE if you sort out the licensing problem. I mentioned the call on `new Processor` because that's where some people go wrong, and you haven't told us anything about how you are invoking the transformation (you might be doing it from the command line or using some other API).